# Can multiple clients communicate with the server at the same time?

Tags: ros, multiple, action-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have already established a client and a server connection. Now I need to have multiple clients all calling for the same service. How can I achieve this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238378/can-multiple-clients-communicate-with-the-server-at-the-same-time?/) by [Pikachu](https://answers.ros.org/users/22900/pikachu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2016-06-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There can only be a single server providing a service using a given graph resource name. That server can have an unlimited number of clients. The clients can be distributed amongst different nodes or in the same node. The clients can all have individual settings for persistence.

All you need to achieve this is to create additional `rospy.ServiceProxy()` objects or `ros::ServiceClient` objects.

Note that the client library (rospy vs. roscpp) used for the service server will define exactly how client requests are queued/ handled. [The rospy docs](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Services#Providing_services) say " Each inbound request is handled in its own thread, so services must be thread-safe." In roscpp, services are handled with [callback queues and spinning](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning) (just like topics).

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2016-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0